# OpenGL Light Position

Tags: opengl, light

I'm having a problem with light's position in opengl.

I change the position of the light but the light source is always at the center.

[image: i.stack.imgur.com/uXZR8.png]

this is some code I have...

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT1);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, LightAmbient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, LightDiffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, LightPosition);
```

...

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();



look[0] = player->dir[0] + player->cam[0];
look[1] = player->dir[1] + player->cam[1];
look[2] = player->dir[2] + player->cam[2];

normalize_vector(player->dir);
glNormal3f(player->dir[0],player->dir[1],player->dir[2]);
gluLookAt(player->cam[0],player->cam[1],player->cam[2],
look[0],look[1],look[2],0, 0, 1);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, player->light_pos);
```

...

```
void glNormalVec(float * vec){
glNormal3f(vec[0],vec[1],vec[2]);
}
void glVertexPoint(POINT * p){
glVertex3f (p->p[0],p->p[1],p->p[2]);
}
```

...

```
glNormalVec(tri->point[0]->p);
glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertexPoint(tri->point[0]);
glNormalVec(tri->point[1]->p);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertexPoint(tri->point[1]);
glNormalVec(tri->point[2]->p);
glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertexPoint(tri->point[2]);
```

A point has a float3 and a normal vector.
A triangle has 3 points.
cam0 is x.
cam1 is y.
cam2 is z.

I made a solution with my own calculations (with dot prodtuct and glColor3f)
But I want to use OpenGL functions.
Here is the result with my solution: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aVFS.png]

Comment: How is player->light_pos computed?

Comment: Is it a proper pointer to array [0..3] of GLFloat?

Comment: Why don't you use your own solution if it works? Opengl should only be used to display stuff to the screen. Any calculations should ideally be done yourself and the results of the calculations passed to opengl.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry I solved the problem myself.
 I forgot to normalize some vectors.

Comment: -1 for not posting the solution, so others can learn from your mistakes.